# $327.68 Knuth reward check

Tags: errors, knuth, tex-history

I know something about $327.68 Knuth reward check. However, I cannot find a comprehensive list of people rewarded for finding errors in TeX. I do know, that among them is Bogusław Jackowski (Twice, for TeX and METAFONT. In late 70's in Poland an annual salary was about the value of the "big" check). Marek Ryćko and Piotr Strzelczyk obtained "small" checks.

Any piece of information about other people, any source (well... not Wikipedia), any additional information would be very interesting for me.

Some of SX users are winners of Knuth's checks. Their knowledge may be invaluable.

Comment: A partial list of people rewarded is available at http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~knuth/address.html

Comment: @PrzemyslawScherwentke just now you have edited your question adding (well... not Wikipedia). Please, should I delete my answer?

Comment: @Papiro No, you shouldn't. The answer is, as we can see, valuable for others. However I had earlier known all sources, given in comments or in your answer.

Comment: i'm not sure it's possible for anyone but knuth to compile such a list.  as "tex entomologist", i have files on the reports since just before 1990, but i don't have all the records for who received checks in what amount.  some of this information has been reported in knuth's periodic "tuneup" reports in tugboat.  the most recent, in issue 35:1 (2014) reported that oleg bulatov found what knuth hopes is "the final bug" in tex; unfortunately, owing to the delay since the report was received, the address oleg had used was no longer valid -- if anyone knows his whereabouts, please let me know!

Comment: @Papiro -- the list you cite includes people who have found glitches in *the art of computer programming"; i don't recognize any of those names as being for people who reported tex bugs.  see my previous comment.

Comment: Account balances in The Bank of San Serriffe
http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~knuth/boss.html

Comment: Among people who have received rewards [since 2006](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/boss.html), there are, at the moment, only eight who have received at least $327.68 (= 0x$80.00). The two of them with exactly that amount are both mentioned in [The TeX tuneup of 2014](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109knut.pdf) as recipients of $327.68 rewards.

Answer (score 74):

As a bit of history: Don told me at one point that he did chose Wells Fargo Bank for this because they had such nice checks at the time (with a carriage drawn by four horses - see picture) and that he therefore hoped most people would put the checks on the wall rather than cashing them:

[image]

These days I think they are no longer that beautiful, but I haven't seen one in the last years.

Comment: Words cannot express the awesomeness. Wow! `:)`

Comment: omigosh!  that's a duane bibby drawing i've never seen!  (i think it's a terrible way to treat our favorite lion.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's as far as I know one that Duane made privatly for Leslie but Leslie decided not to be so brutal as to put it into the LaTeX manual :-)

Answer (score 70):

The TeX error log lists the people who have reported bugs that resulted in changes to TeX the program. I assume they all have cheques

```
generic/knuth/errata/errorlog.pdf
```

or just use the command

```
texdoc errorlog
```

in TeX Live at least.

Comment: This file is entertaining reading, too.  "14 Mar 1978:
(Came in evening after sleeping most of day, to get computer at better time.)//(Some day we will have personal computers and will live more normally.)"

Comment: @RyanReich TeX is designed for a different era:-)

Comment: [Direct link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/errata/errorlog.pdf) to pdf of the error log.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is the type of information I have expected! To my surprise I have found only Bogusław Jackowski among potential Polish owners. I will check this piece of information in a few days.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke it seems that a number of names are abbreviated ... couldn't find my name at all until I realized that it was reduced to two letters :-). On the other hand TeX is one of the programs with the lowest number of bugs whatsoever, you really had to come up with weird scenarios to make it trip, as a result there aren't that many different people who found bugs (compared to finding typos in his books).

Comment: "Beginning at 2:30am" appear twice in this document.

Comment: @BarbaraBeeton Actually ... was just wondering if there is listing somewhere of the abbreviated names somewhere close by. If not perhaps one should compile one and suggest to Don to include it into the file ... it is a shame if that kind of info gets lost on who is PB (Peter Breitenlohner) and DRK (David Fuchs?) etc

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: The file errorlog.tex is meant as an appendix to Knuth's paper 'The Errors of \TeX' (Chapter 10 in his book 'Literate Programming'). Chapter 11 is the error log; it contains an introduction that is not part of errorlog.tex. There the abbreviations are explained: DRF stands for David Fuchs, ARK for Arthur Keller.
The used abbreviations are also stated at the end of errorlog.tex after the \bye. All names with the remark ``added subsequent to publication of paper'' are listed in Chapter 11 too.

Comment: @UdoWermuth thanks, good info. In that case the list is close by.

Answer (score 44):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check):

> According to an article in the Massachusetts Institute of Technology's
>   Technology Review, these rewards have been described as "among
>   computerdom's most prized trophies". As of October 2001, Knuth reports
>   having written more than 2,000 checks, with an average value exceeding
>   $8 per check. As of March 2005, the total value of the checks signed
>   by Knuth was over $20,000 (see NPR interview below). Very few of these
>   checks are actually cashed, however, even the largest ones. More often
>   they are framed or kept as "bragging rights".
>
> > "Intelligence: Finding an error in a Knuth text. Stupidity: Cashing
> >     that $2.56 check you got.” —Seen in a Slashdot signature, quoted by
> >     Edward O'Connor

**EDIT:** 
A list of people who have reported errors in `Knuth's books` from the beginning of 2006 to 9 March 2013 is available [here](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/boss.html).

**EDIT:** [+1](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/donald%20knuth?language=pt_PT) :)

[image: Dear Reader: Enclosed is a check for ninety-eight cents. Using your work, I have proven that this equals the amount you requested.]

Comment: The above is (of course) from: http://www.xkcd.com/816/ --- it's well worth visiting the site to get the mouse-over.

Comment: [xkcd 816 elaborated](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/816:_Applied_Math)