# LaTeX mascots/associated animals

Tags: tex-history

Some different animals have been associated with LaTeX, depending on where you look.

If i look on [this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com) I will most likely come to believe, that the mascot of LaTeX is a duck.

If i look at the [official LaTeX project](https://www.latex-project.org/) I end up thinking: The mascot is a hummingbird.

And last but not least, if I look at google i might think either:

[1](https://www.google.fi/search?q=latex+mascot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=2emnWrmQGM3GsAHO4I7IAQ) lion

[2](https://www.google.fi/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&ei=2emnWvLtGauRmgX0gq_ABw&q=latex+project&oq=latex+project&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1l10.40620.42478.0.42557.13.10.0.3.3.0.93.797.10.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.13.851...0j35i39k1j0i67k1.0.vHafR9UnO80) hummingbird

[3](https://www.google.fi/search?q=latex+typography+animal&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=3dnTNcrLzu4LyM%253A%252ClRWrgcD5cLyP0M%252C_&usg=__XLXBw3-3OojmSqxbDgoXhr5yNnE%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz0qfnyunZAhUE2ywKHR-AA44Q9QEILDAC#imgrc=3dnTNcrLzu4LyM:) some sort of chicken monster (.

The questions then stands:

Is there any official LaTeX master animal over them all? does the lion rule the TeX jungle? Are there other, non obvious animals that associate themselves with LaTeX?

Comment: I ask this question because I reasently discovered the lion on [meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7529/who-plans-to-go-to-tug-2018-in-rio-de-janeiro) and I would like to know of other cool animal mascots.

Comment: Related/duplicate? [Why does TeX have a lion as mascot?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/49087)

Comment: @AlanMunn IT answers why the lion is a mascot, but not what others there are, which are more "official" and why they are there. So while I agree that it's related, I don't think of it as a duplicate.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I know, it's just not the first impression one would get if looking for animals related to LaTeX on the site. (I asked the question you cited).

Comment: Donkeys and bird-donkey hybrids. See [I need a TeX donkey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312199/i-need-a-tex-donkey)

Comment: @Fran is that a wider spread thing (like the lion, duck and hummingbird) or more situational (like the crazed chicken)?

Comment: As widespread as the several answers to the question. `:)`  The only official equine TeX is [the horse](http://www.cervantex.es/files/cervantex/cervanTeX%20final%20color.jpg) of the  logo of the Spanish TeX Users Group (CervanTeX).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The Lion is the TeX mascot used extensively in the TeXBook

[image]

- The Lioness is his companion, representing MetaFont

[image]

- LaTeX traditionally used a different Lion

[image]

- Recently the LaTeX(3) project has adopted the Hummingbird as its logo used on the project website and elsewhere

[image]

- Ducks have no official connection to anything, despite appearances to the contrary if you follow this site:-)

[image]

Comment: +1; the mascots of TeX and METAFONT are IIRC called “TeX the lion” and “Meta the lioness” (i.e., they represent the programs themselves, and are not quite mascots in the modern sense… whatever that means :P). That the LaTeX lion(? big cat?) is different from the TeX lion can be seen in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/327-68-knuth-reward-check/113658#113658) (WARNING: contains disturbing images). Looking around I also found there's a mascot for [the macro package `eplain`](https://tug.org/eplain/), named “TeXimilian”.

Comment: Might I ask if there is any history behind the hummingbird? Is it just chosen for fun, or to compliment the duck the same way the lioness compliments the lion?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen ask Paulo, he drew it:-)

Answer (score 3):

The most recent mascot and logo is a hummingbird. To add to the book cover collection, here's my recent cover:

[image: LaTeX Beginner's Guide]

Comment: By the way, isn't it more appropriate here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thanks, this is much better to me now. You can (and should) mention credits to your publisher, e.g. in your last sentence “recent cover (credits to my publisher for designing it):”.

Comment: Much better now, but I think you may update this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15178/101651